# DYNAMICALLY CALCULATE BALANCE FOR EACH USER W UNIQUE ACC_ID

Tags: mysql, sql

so, I have been trying to create a ledger-like database using MySQL.

which primarily, stores the transaction history of all Users done throughout the app, regardless of the type(Credit/Debit) and User.

This ledger-like database is also responsible for dynamically calculating the balance, after each deposit (credits)[it will also calculate the balance dynamically for each debit, but for simplicity let's just focus on one type).

The link to the SQL fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fJFXgn9D5CkxSAaM7S2d8H/3

What I Intend to do is *calculate the balance of each user (with a unique acc_id) based on their transactions only* but the output (you will see in the sql fiddle) is basically adding up the balances for all entry regardless of the entry and the acc who did that.

I am leaving an Image to briefly summarise the challenge at hand...
[image]

so, it was going nice for the first 4 records, with acc_id VA473, and the balance was also calculated properly.
But the 5th and 6th entry, was by a different acc_id, but the balance is being calculated from the 4th entry.

the correct balance for 5th row will be: (balance + credit - debit) => (0 + (100 -0)) = 100. [assuming the balance will be 0 if not set otherwise)

and 6th row  will be: (balance + credit - debit) => (100 + (150-0)) = 250

Thanks in advance for helping :)

Comment: Does your MySQL version is 5.7 really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  utr VARCHAR(255),
  acc_id VARCHAR(255),
  credit INT,
  debit INT
  );
INSERT INTO test (id, utr, acc_id, credit, debit) VALUES (1, 'xxyyzz1', 'VA743', 30, 0);
INSERT INTO test (id, utr, acc_id, credit, debit) VALUES (2, 'xxyyzz2', 'VA743', 70, 0);
INSERT INTO test (id, utr, acc_id, credit, debit) VALUES (3, 'xxyyzz3', 'VA743', 80, 0);
INSERT INTO test (id, utr, acc_id, credit, debit) VALUES (4, 'xxyyzz4', 'VA700', 80, 0);
INSERT INTO test (id, utr, acc_id, credit, debit) VALUES (5, 'xxyyzz5', 'VA700', 70, 0);
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | utr | acc_id | credit | debit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xxyyzz1 | VA743 | 30 | 0 |
| 2 | xxyyzz2 | VA743 | 70 | 0 |
| 3 | xxyyzz3 | VA743 | 80 | 0 |
| 4 | xxyyzz4 | VA700 | 80 | 0 |
| 5 | xxyyzz5 | VA700 | 70 | 0 |

```
SELECT @balance := (acc_id = @acc_id) * @balance + credit - debit balance,
       test.id,
       test.utr,
       @acc_id := test.acc_id acc_id,
       test.credit,
       test.debit
FROM test
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @balance:=0, @acc_id:='') init_variables
ORDER BY test.acc_id, test.id;
```

| balance | id | utr | acc_id | credit | debit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 80 | 4 | xxyyzz4 | VA700 | 80 | 0 |
| 150 | 5 | xxyyzz5 | VA700 | 70 | 0 |
| 30 | 1 | xxyyzz1 | VA743 | 30 | 0 |
| 100 | 2 | xxyyzz2 | VA743 | 70 | 0 |
| 180 | 3 | xxyyzz3 | VA743 | 80 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uYefS5zW)

Pay attention - the `ORDER BY` clause is added, and its presence is critical. W/o it the query is not deterministic and may produce incorrect output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Sir, it is exactly what I needed.

But with AUTO_INCREMENT it doesn't seem to work, can you look into that? please? I am new to SQL.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fJFXgn9D5CkxSAaM7S2d8H/49

Comment: @DwaipayanChakroborty You alter the columns order in the output which breaks the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the assist, Akina. Reordering the columns, as per your DB, fixed the problem. :D
Could you also be able to say, why did the algo break, by re-ordering the balance column at the last, just curious.

Comment: @DwaipayanChakroborty The output expressions are evaluated in the order in which they are written in the query text (this is not documented but may be found in source code). The expressions in my answer are dependent - in my query `@acc_id` stores `acc_id` value which was assigned for previous row while calculating `@balance` value whereas in your code it was reassigned with `acc_id` value for current row.